# DevExpress one Ribbon for multiple RichEditControls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress

I have two RichEditControls and one autogenerated Ribbon.

To use the Ribbon for both Controls, I did the following (guided by [this suggestion](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q225063/copy-paste-with-two-richeditcontrols)):

1. I added this in my XAML: `<dxre:RichEditControlProvider x:Name="recp" />`
2. This is my XAML.CS

   ```
   public TaskView()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       richEditControl1.GotFocus += RichEditControl1OnGotFocus;
       richEditControl2.GotFocus += RichEditControl2OnGotFocus;
   }


   private void RichEditControl1OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   {
       recp.RichEditControl = richEditControl1;
       richEditControl2.BarManager = null;
       richEditControl1.BarManager = barManager1;
   }


   private void RichEditControl2OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   {
       recp.RichEditControl = richEditControl2;
       richEditControl1.BarManager = null;
       richEditControl2.BarManager = barManager1;
   }
   ```

This allows me to use the ribbon for the second RichEditControl as well.

**My problem now is that there are optional RibbonPages table editing and image editing, these are only shown when a table or image is selected.
Unfortunately these do not get synchronized with selected RichEditControl, so I can only use them for the first control.**

This is the auto generated XAML code for the picture editing pages:

Ribbon:

```
                <dxr:RibbonPageCategory x:Name="catPictureTools"
                                        Caption="{Binding ConverterParameter=Caption_PageCategoryFloatingObjectPictureTools, Converter={StaticResource stringIdConverter}, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource stringIdConverter}}"
                                        dxre:AttachedCommand.Command="{Binding ToolsFloatingPictureCommandGroup, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource commands}}">
                    <dxr:RibbonPage x:Name="pagePictureToolsFormat"
                                    Caption="{Binding ConverterParameter=Caption_PageFloatingObjectPictureToolsFormat, Converter={StaticResource stringIdConverter}, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource stringIdConverter}}">
                        <dxr:RibbonPageGroup x:Name="grpPictureToolsFormatShapeStyles"
                                             Caption="{Binding ConverterParameter=Caption_GroupFloatingPictureToolsShapeStyles, Converter={StaticResource stringIdConverter}, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource stringIdConverter}}"
                                             ShowCaptionButton="False">
                            <dxr:RibbonPageGroup.ItemLinks>
                                <dxr:BarButtonGroupLink BarItemName="biShapeColors" />
                                <dxr:BarButtonGroupLink BarItemName="biShapeOutlineWeight" />
                            </dxr:RibbonPageGroup.ItemLinks>
                        </dxr:RibbonPageGroup>
                        <dxr:RibbonPageGroup x:Name="grpPictureToolsFormatArrange"
                                             Caption="{Binding ConverterParameter=Caption_GroupFloatingPictureToolsArrange, Converter={StaticResource stringIdConverter}, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource stringIdConverter}}"
                                             ShowCaptionButton="False">
                            <dxr:RibbonPageGroup.ItemLinks>
                                <dxb:BarSubItemLink BarItemName="biPictureWrapText" />
                                <dxb:BarSubItemLink BarItemName="biPicturePosition" />
                                <dxb:BarSubItemLink BarItemName="biPictureBringForwardPlaceholder" />
                                <dxb:BarSubItemLink BarItemName="biPictureSendBackwardPlaceholder" />
                            </dxr:RibbonPageGroup.ItemLinks>
                        </dxr:RibbonPageGroup>
                    </dxr:RibbonPage>
                </dxr:RibbonPageCategory>
```

BarItems:

```
            <dxr:BarButtonGroup x:Name="biShapeColors">
                <dxr:BarButtonGroup.ItemLinks>
                    <dxre:BarSplitButtonColorEditItemLink BarItemName="biPictureShapeFillColor" />
                    <dxre:BarSplitButtonColorEditItemLink BarItemName="biPictureShapeOutlineColor" />
                </dxr:BarButtonGroup.ItemLinks>
            </dxr:BarButtonGroup>
            <dxre:BarSplitButtonColorEditItem x:Name="biPictureShapeFillColor"
                                              Command="{Binding PictureShapeFillColor, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource commands}}">
                <dxb:PopupControlContainerInfo>
                    <dxe:ColorEdit EditValue="{Binding EditValue, ElementName=biPictureShapeFillColor, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                   ShowDefaultColorButton="False"
                                   ShowNoColorButton="True"
                                   ShowBorder="False" />
                </dxb:PopupControlContainerInfo>
            </dxre:BarSplitButtonColorEditItem>
            <dxre:BarSplitButtonColorEditItem x:Name="biPictureShapeOutlineColor"
                                              Command="{Binding PictureShapeOutlineColor, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource commands}}">
                <dxb:PopupControlContainerInfo>
                    <dxe:ColorEdit EditValue="{Binding EditValue, ElementName=biPictureShapeOutlineColor, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                   ShowDefaultColorButton="False"
                                   ShowNoColorButton="True"
                                   ShowBorder="False" />
                </dxb:PopupControlContainerInfo>
            </dxre:BarSplitButtonColorEditItem>
            <dxr:BarButtonGroup x:Name="biShapeOutlineWeight">
                <dxr:BarButtonGroup.ItemLinks>
                    <dxb:BarEditItemLink BarItemName="biPictureShapeOutlineWeight" />
                </dxr:BarButtonGroup.ItemLinks>
            </dxr:BarButtonGroup>
            <dxb:BarEditItem x:Name="biPictureShapeOutlineWeight"
                             Content=""
                             Command="{Binding PictureShapeOutlineWeight, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource commands}}"
                             EditWidth="150">
                <dxb:BarEditItem.EditSettings>
                    <dxre:RichEditBorderLineWidthEditSettings RichEditControl="{Binding ElementName=richEditControl1}" />
                </dxb:BarEditItem.EditSettings>
            </dxb:BarEditItem>
            <dxb:BarSubItem x:Name="biPictureWrapText"
                            Command="{Binding PictureWrapText, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource commands}}">
                <dxb:BarSubItem.ItemLinks>
                    <dxb:BarCheckItemLink BarItemName="biPictureWrapTextSquare" />
                    <dxb:BarCheckItemLink BarItemName="biPictureWrapTextTight" />
                    <dxb:BarCheckItemLink BarItemName="biPictureWrapTextThrough" />
                    <dxb:BarCheckItemLink BarItemName="biPictureWrapTextTopAndBottom" />
                    <dxb:BarCheckItemLink BarItemName="biPictureWrapTextBehind" />
                    <dxb:BarCheckItemLink BarItemName="biPictureWrapTextInFrontOf" />
                </dxb:BarSubItem.ItemLinks>
            </dxb:BarSubItem>
            <dxb:BarCheckItem x:Name="biPictureWrapTextSquare"
                              Command="{Binding PictureWrapTextSquare, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource commands}}" />
            <dxb:BarCheckItem x:Name="biPictureWrapTextTight"
                              Command="{Binding PictureWrapTextTight, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource commands}}" />
            <dxb:BarCheckItem x:Name="biPictureWrapTextThrough"
                              Command="{Binding PictureWrapTextThrough, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource commands}}" />
            <dxb:BarCheckItem x:Name="biPictureWrapTextTopAndBottom"
                              Command="{Binding PictureWrapTextTopAndBottom, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource commands}}" />
            <dxb:BarCheckItem x:Name="biPictureWrapTextBehind"
                              Command="{Binding PictureWrapTextBehind, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource commands}}" />
            <dxb:BarCheckItem x:Name="biPictureWrapTextInFrontOf"
                              Command="{Binding PictureWrapTextInFrontOf, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource commands}}" />
            <dxb:BarSubItem x:Name="biPicturePosition"
                            Command="{Binding PicturePosition, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource commands}}">
                <dxb:BarSubItem.ItemLinks>
                    <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="biPictureTopLeftAlignment" />
                    <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="biPictureTopCenterAlignment" />
                    <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="biPictureTopRightAlignment" />
                    <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="biPictureMiddleLeftAlignment" />
                    <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="biPictureMiddleCenterAlignment" />
                    <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="biPictureMiddleRightAlignment" />
                    <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="biPictureBottomLeftAlignment" />
                    <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="biPictureBottomCenterAlignment" />
                    <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="biPictureBottomRightAlignment" />
                </dxb:BarSubItem.ItemLinks>
            </dxb:BarSubItem>
            <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="biPictureTopLeftAlignment"
                               Command="{Binding PictureTopLeftAlignment, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource commands}}" />
            <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="biPictureTopCenterAlignment"
                               Command="{Binding PictureTopCenterAlignment, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource commands}}" />
            <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="biPictureTopRightAlignment"
                               Command="{Binding PictureTopRightAlignment, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource commands}}" />
            <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="biPictureMiddleLeftAlignment"
                               Command="{Binding PictureMiddleLeftAlignment, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource commands}}" />
            <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="biPictureMiddleCenterAlignment"
                               Command="{Binding PictureMiddleCenterAlignment, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource commands}}" />
            <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="biPictureMiddleRightAlignment"
                               Command="{Binding PictureMiddleRightAlignment, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource commands}}" />
            <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="biPictureBottomLeftAlignment"
                               Command="{Binding PictureBottomLeftAlignment, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource commands}}" />
            <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="biPictureBottomCenterAlignment"
                               Command="{Binding PictureBottomCenterAlignment, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource commands}}" />
            <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="biPictureBottomRightAlignment"
                               Command="{Binding PictureBottomRightAlignment, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource commands}}" />
            <dxb:BarSubItem x:Name="biPictureBringForwardPlaceholder"
                            Command="{Binding PictureBringForwardPlaceholder, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource commands}}">
                <dxb:BarSubItem.ItemLinks>
                    <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="biPictureBringForward" />
                    <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="biPictureBringToFront" />
                    <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="biPictureBringInFrontOfText" />
                </dxb:BarSubItem.ItemLinks>
            </dxb:BarSubItem>
            <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="biPictureBringForward"
                               Command="{Binding PictureBringForward, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource commands}}" />
            <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="biPictureBringToFront"
                               Command="{Binding PictureBringToFront, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource commands}}" />
            <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="biPictureBringInFrontOfText"
                               Command="{Binding PictureBringInFrontOfText, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource commands}}" />
            <dxb:BarSubItem x:Name="biPictureSendBackwardPlaceholder"
                            Command="{Binding PictureSendBackwardPlaceholder, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource commands}}">
                <dxb:BarSubItem.ItemLinks>
                    <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="biPictureSendBackward" />
                    <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="biPictureSendToBack" />
                    <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="biPictureSendBehindText" />
                </dxb:BarSubItem.ItemLinks>
            </dxb:BarSubItem>
            <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="biPictureSendBackward"
                               Command="{Binding PictureSendBackward, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource commands}}" />
            <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="biPictureSendToBack"
                               Command="{Binding PictureSendToBack, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource commands}}" />
            <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="biPictureSendBehindText"
                               Command="{Binding PictureSendBehindText, Mode=OneTime, Source={StaticResource commands}}" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I have found an answer.
*When I asked my question I hadn't done steps 5 and 6 yet. Also code was missing in the code-behind.*

**If you want to have multiple RichEditControls with one ribbon, follow these steps:**

1. Add one RichEditControl (e.g. with drag and drop from the toolbox)
2. Autogenerate your Ribbon:
   [image]

   - In the designer click on the button in top right corner (1)
   - Select one ribbon page or all (2)
   - Autogenerate it by clicking on the blue text (3) Do this multiple times to generate more pages
3. Add your second RichEditControl
4. Now add a RichEditControlProvider somewhere in your xaml-code.
5. Use the Visual Studio replace function (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) to replace all `Binding ElementName=richEditControl1` with `Binding Path=RichEditControl, ElementName=richEditControlProvider1` or whatever your first RichEditControl and your RichEditControlProvider are called.
6. Clear the `BarManager` and `Ribbon` properties of your richEditControl1.
7. Code-Behind:

   ```
   public MyView()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       richEditControl1.GotFocus += RichEditControl1OnGotFocus;
       richEditControl2.GotFocus += RichEditControl2OnGotFocus;
       RichEditControl1OnGotFocus(null, null);
   }


   private void RichEditControl1OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   {
       richEditControlProvider1.RichEditControl = richEditControl1;
       richEditControl1.Ribbon = ribbonControl1;
       richEditControl2.Ribbon = null;
       richEditControl1.BarManager = barManager1;
       richEditControl2.BarManager = null;
   }


   private void RichEditControl2OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   {
       richEditControlProvider1.RichEditControl = richEditControl2;
       richEditControl1.Ribbon = null;
       richEditControl2.Ribbon = ribbonControl1;
       richEditControl1.BarManager = null;
       richEditControl2.BarManager = barManager1;
   }
   ```